# Mongodb group by function giving unexpected data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB for grouping the data based on data inserted `hours & minutes`. But its giving strange and unexpected results.

I want `hours & minutes` in **2-digits** if they are in `Single Digit`.

For example, **if hour is 9, I want it to be, 09** and same with minutes too.

Following is the grouping function I've used.

```
$group: {
    _id: {
        hour: { 
            '$hour': { date: '$entryDayTime', timezone: '+0530' } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the data I'm getting after using `$group`.

```
{ _id: { hour: 10, minute: 5 }, value: 26 },
{ _id: { hour: 9, minute: 55 }, value: 260 }
```

But I want the result in the following pattern.

```
{ _id: { hour: 10, minute: 05 }, value: 26 },
{ _id: { hour: 09, minute: 55 }, value: 260 }
```

Is there any options to be provided in `$group` to get the **hours & minutes** in `double digits if they are in single digits`

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `$cond`

[mongo-play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXHuW0qQ34Q)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hour: {
          "$hour": {
            date: "$key",
            timezone: "+0530"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "hour": {
        "$cond": [ //Condition
          {
            "$lte": [ //Less than 9
              "$_id.hour",
              9
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concat": [ //Concatenate 0, Concat works only Strings
              "0",
              {
                "$toString": "$_id.hour"
              }
            ]
          },
          { //To keep only string for > 9 cases
            "$toString": "$_id.hour"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update:**

To include minutes, add another variable.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_d-AZ3vMz6-)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hour: {
          "$hour": {
            date: "$key",
            timezone: "+0530"
          }
        },
        minute: {//Including minute also
          "$minute": {
            date: "$key",
            timezone: "+0530"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "hour": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$lte": [//Checking less than 9
              "$_id.hour",
              9
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concat": [//Concatenating 0
              "0",
              {
                "$toString": "$_id.hour"
              }
            ]
          },
          {//Same format for >9 cases to maintain uniformity
            "$toString": "$_id.hour"
          }
        ]
      },
      "minute": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$lte": [ //checking less than 9 on minute
              "$_id.minute",
              9
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concat": [ //Concatenating 0
              "0",
              {
                "$toString": "$_id.minute"
              }
            ]
          },
          {//Keeping uniform format - string type
            "$toString": "$_id.minute"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs. But can't I get the data as mentioned in the question? because, I might get hour and minute in some cases. That's why I want 2-digits like this ```{ _id: { hour: 09, minute: 05 }, value: 26 }```.

Comment: Some cases i get the following results, **CASE-1** : ```{ _id: { minute: 05 }, value: 26 }```,

Comment: **CASE-2** : ```{ _id: { hour:  05 }, value: 26 }```

Comment: You mean even hour is 0, you want hour:00?

Comment: Yes, and that too in _id object. I've a lot of conditions based on that object. That is why am sounding some what desperate to get the result in that format

Comment: I am changing that. To confirm again, if hour is 0, you are saying that it is not part of the result. But are you ok with string format result? That's kind of restriction

Comment: @Aravind Can you make a reproducible scenario? That is not happening. [see here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LwEq2qunXYK).

Comment: yeah, i don't want it to be as string and one more thing, if I get minutes, that too be in 2 digits and not to be as string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219654/discussion-between-gibbs-and-aravind).